# Autocomplete using Solr & Spring - issue with multiple words

Tags: java, solr, lucene, spring-data, spring-data-solr

I have indexed a database of locations using Spring Data Solr. I have the following fields:

```
   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
   <field name="name" type="text_ws" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="autocomplete" type="lowercase" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

I am trying to implement an autocomplete feature. My ajax call is handled by a controller which calls a repository with:

```
List<POISearch> findByAutocompleteStartingWith(String autocomplete, Pageable pageable);
```

This works fine with a search like "California" or "Los". But when I try multiple words like "Los Ang" I get an exception:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-mvc] in context with
>   path [/xxx] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Cannot
>   constructQuery '*"los an"*'. Use epxression or mulitple clauses
>   instead.] with root cause
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Cannot
>   constructQuery '*"los an"*'. Use epxression or mulitple clauses
>   instead.  at
>   org.springframework.data.solr.core.query.Criteria.assertNoBlankInWildcardedQuery(Criteria.java:596)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.solr.core.query.Criteria.contains(Criteria.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.solr.core.query.Criteria.contains(Criteria.java:257)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.solr.core.query.Criteria.contains(Criteria.java:244)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.solr.repository.query.SolrQueryCreator.from(SolrQueryCreator.java:112)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.solr.repository.query.SolrQueryCreator.create(SolrQueryCreator.java:56)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.solr.repository.query.SolrQueryCreator.create(SolrQueryCreator.java:43)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.solr.repository.query.PartTreeSolrQuery.createQuery(PartTreeSolrQuery.java:46)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.solr.repository.query.AbstractSolrQuery.execute(AbstractSolrQuery.java:95)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>     at $Proxy44.findByAutocompleteContaining(Unknown Source)

Any ideas how to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest version of spring-data-solr you can do the following:

```
List<POISearch> results = repository.findByAutocompleteStartingWith(Arrays.asList("los", "ange"));
```

Works great!

Thanks to Christoph for helping with an answer: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATASOLR-74

Comment: Is it possible to search by multiple words and multiple fields at the same time? For example, searching by the field "title" and "content" and having multiple-word query? I'm trying right now with something like `findByContentOrTitle(List<String> s1, List<String> s2>)`, but I'm having an error similar to `org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'content:[a] OR title:*a*': Encountered " "]" "] "" at line 1`..

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can't perform a wildcard query on a phrase, which is what it appears is happening here.

I don't know about the implementation of `findByAutocompleteStartingWith`, but it appears it's just building a `PrefixQuery`, or something like that.  That exception is being thrown by an assertion, so it is designed very explicitly only to make single-word suggestions for single-word queries.

As such, you'll only be able to pass one word into it.  Generally, the last word entered.

Comment: I see why the exception is thrown. So how do I make a two-word (or three... etc.) queries?

Comment: As I said, with that call, you don't.  I don't have access to `findByAutocompleteStartingWith`, obviously, but it looks very much like it does not provide that capability.  Apart from that call, you can create Wildcard Phrase queries with [ComplexPhraseQueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/complexPhrase/ComplexPhraseQueryParser.html)....

Comment: Or better yet, by indexing the field as a Keyword, and searching for it using a standard prefix (or possibly wildcard) query as a single term.  Whether this is appropriate depends on what you are searching, but sounds like it may be well suited to what you are doing ("Los Angeles" is an identifier that it makes sense to index as a keyword, for instance).